# Showing progress bar in splashscreen while data is getting downloaded from the internet

Tags: android, fragment, background-process

I need to know how to parse data from online xml in the background and show it in listview.

Presently I have a class which is extending FragmentActivity. Below is the layout of the class

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/pager"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I have declared Action bar tabs and view pager in the class like below

```
    actionbar = getActionBar();      
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);    
    actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);       
    actionbar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);      
    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);       
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});





     ActionBar.Tab TabOne = actionbar.newTab().setText("TabOne ");
     ActionBar.Tab TabTwo = actionbar.newTab().setText("TabTwo ");
     ActionBar.Tab TabThree = actionbar.newTab().setText("TabThree ");
     ActionBar.Tab TabFour = actionbar.newTab().setText("TabFour ");
     ActionBar.Tab TabFive = actionbar.newTab().setText("TabFive ");
     ActionBar.Tab TabSix = actionbar.newTab().setText("TabSix ");


     TabOneActivity one = new TabOneActivity ();        
     TabTwoActivity two= new TabTwoActivity ();
     TabThreeActivity  three= new TabThreeActivity  ();
     TabFourActivity four= new TabFourActivity ();
     TabOFiveActivity five= new TabOFiveActivity ();
     TabSixActivity six=new TabSixActivity ();


     TabOne .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(one));
     TabTwo .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(two));
     TabThree .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(three));
     TabFour .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(four));
     TabFive .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(five));
     TabSix .setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(six));

     actionbar.addTab(TabOne);
     actionbar.addTab(TabTwo);
     actionbar.addTab(TabThree);
     actionbar.addTab(TabFour);        
     actionbar.addTab(TabFive);
     actionbar.addTab(TabSix);
```

There are two inner classes  MyTabListener and  ViewPageAdapter  . Below is the MyTabListener class

```
  public class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
protected TabOneActivity oneContext;
protected TabTwoActivity twoContext;
protected TabThreeActivity threeContext;
protected TabFourActivity fourContext;
protected TabFiveActivity fiveContext;
protected TabSixActivity sixcontext;


public MyTabsListener(TabOneActivity onetab) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.oneContext=onetab;
}

public MyTabsListener(TabTwoActivity twoTab) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.twoContext=twoTab;
}
public MyTabsListener(TabThreeActivity threeTab) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.threeContext=threeTab;
}
public MyTabsListener(TabFourActivity fourTab) {
    this.fourContext= fourTab;
}
public MyTabsListener(TabFiveActivity fiveTab) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.fiveContext=fiveTab;
} 
public MyTabsListener(TabSixActivity sixTab) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.sixContext=sixTab;
}



@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {      
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {        
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}
```

Below is the ViewPagerAdapter class

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 6;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super(supportFragmentManager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(position){
case 0:
    return TabOneActivity.create(position);     
case 1:
    return TabTwoActivity.create(position);
case 2:
    return TabThreeActivity.create(position);
case 3:
    return TabFourActivity.create(position);
case 4:
    return TabFiveActivity.create(position);
case 5:
    return TabSixActivity.create(position);
default :
    return TabOneActivity.create(position);
 }     
  }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

  }
```

Each Activity is extending fragment and hitting and parsing online xml using AsyncTask and showing the result in a listview.

Before data gets populated to the listview I am showing a progressbar.

What I need to do is to show a progress bar on the splash screen which in the background should hit and parses the online data and one post execute show the data in a listview.

This will make UI look good, since user don't need to wait for data to get load in the main screen instead it is getting downlaoded in the spalsh screen.

Kindly suggest how to achieve this. Since I am using a FragmentActivity which has six different fragments hitting six different URLs

Comment: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2066699